# Ruby detecting if value is set in variable setting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a function `generate_username` that generates a username (obviously).

The values `fname` and `lname` are mandatory, so no issues there. However, `mname` is NOT a mandatory field so, it may be blank, which breaks this code.

Any suggestions on how to ask ruby to only print the `mname` value if it exists or is set and ignore it if the user left it blank?

```
def generate_username
  self.username = fname.to_s.split("")[0] + mname.to_s.split("")[0] + lname.to_s
end
```

Comment: why are you splitting then taking the first element, why not just do a strip or gsub if you are trying to do something

Comment: I'm new to ruby so I'm not sure of the best techniques to grab the first letter of a string, but I'll look these up thanks :)

Comment: You are a member for two months, asked 10 questions, and so far accepted none of them. I should have noticed that before I answered it. Then, I wouldn't have answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this (parentheses are important):

```
def generate_username
  self.username = fname.to_s.split("")[0] << (mname.to_s.split("")[0] || "") << lname.to_s
end
```

Comment: Hm, this seems sound to me, but I'm getting a can't find '+' function. Thanks, though (for putting up with my newb question)

Comment: Did you put the parentheses? (in case the error was: NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for false:FalseClass)

Comment: Helped a bit but still getting `can't convert nil into String`

Comment: Indeed it returns nil, didn't see this coming. Bear with me a moment :) I am coming back.

Comment: Cool! If it works and helped don't forget to check it as an accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Throwing a simple ternary operator in to check if the value is [blank?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F) should do the trick.

```
def generate_username
  self.username = fname.to_s.split("")[0] + (mname.blank? ? "" : mname.to_s.split("")[0]) + lname.to_s
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In ruby 1.9

```
def generate_username
  "#{fname[0]}#{mname.to_s[0]}#{lname}"
end
```

or

```
def generate_username
  fname[0]+mname.to_s[0].to_s+lname
end
```

In ruby 1.8, replace all the `[0]` with `[0, 1]` (This point added after being pointed out by Peter).

- `mname.to_s` ensures you get a string; when `mname` is `nil` it will be an empty string `""`.
- `String#[0]` picks up the first character of that string; when the string is empty, it will return `nil`.
- `#{  }` within `"   "` expands the ruby code, and turns it into a string; particularly turns `nil` into an empty string `""`.

Comment: +1! But in my 1.8.7 ruby, `fname[0]` gives me a Fixnum instead of the first character (while 1.9.2 gives me the first character ;D)

Comment: @PeterWong I forgot about that. In ruby1.8.7, probably `[0,1]` will work.

Comment: Love the simplicity of `fname[0]` over `fname.split("")[0]` :D